# Is there anything to signify that something which may very understandable and easily be seen as an error actually isn’t?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, style

For example, “the rationale which the omission was justified by by the director” contains a consecutive repetition of the word “by,” which is of course intended.

What is meant is to refer to “the rationale *by* which the omission was justified *by* the director”.

But often words are repeated mistakenly and the correct grammatical parsing may not be readily apparent, so is there any sort of marking or signifier to show that actually, while the author is aware it may at first seem as though there is likely to be one, there is no error as it may understandably appear?

Almost like an inverse of “sic”. Or like an umlaut for repeated vowels which signifies that each one makes its own sound and thus serves its own purpose and so both are to be considered/parsed individually.

Comment: The example isn't a good one, since it is almost impossible to understand.  The "solution" is not to mark as "intentional" but to rephrase.

Comment: As a general note,  when asking "does this feature exist in English",  it is always good to note a language in which it does exist.  If you can say "in German, this would be marked as [Entschuldigung]" that can help us to find examples and understand the question better.  If no other language has this feature - then you might try to explain why you think English might have it.

Comment: Does it in fact exist as entschuldigung in German?

Comment: No.... I made that up.  I guess, from your use of "umlaut" that you might be a german speaker.

Comment: You could write a comment like "(and yes I do mean that!)" at least in an informal context, but generally you're expected to avoid confusing expressions, particularly if you notice them and realise that they're confusing.

Comment: @JamesK isn’t that what the accent is called in the English context as well? As in reëntry, or coördination?

Comment: We don't use dieresis or accents on reentry or coordination. You can spell with a hyphen "re-entry" but this is usually considered unnecessary.  The main use of dieresis is in words borrowed from French,  and some names (Chloë for example) it is always optional, though some people prefer to use the dieresis.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such editorial mark in English.

It is, in general, the writer's task to write clear prose, not the task of the reader to understand unclear prose.

If a grammatical construction is used in a way that results in confusion for the reader, it is the duty of the writer to fix it. And so there is no marking that means "This is unclear or confusing, but it is up to you to work out what I mean."

This is unlike [sic], which is used because it is the duty of the writer to quote precisely, preserving mistakes.  Also the "umlaut" (properly called a dieresis) is hardly used in English.

So, in the example given, the proper course of action is to rewrite - probably with an active verb:  "The director justified the omission by giving the rationale..."  or something similar.

The author is always free to use punctuation to clarify.  Parenthetical remarks may be useful in some cases.